# Injecting a service into a provider

Tags: angularjs

I need to get a token which is saved on my controller in app.js, so I created a service

```
var app = angular.module('UnikaPage', ['LocalStorageModule','RutasModule','UploadModule']);
app.service('AuthService', function() {
        var kc = {};

        var setKeycloak = function(keycloak) {
            kc = keycloak;
        };

        var getKeycloak = function(){
            return kc;
        };

        return {
            setKeycloak: setKeycloak,
            getKeycloak: getKeycloak
        };

    });
```

My other module is UploadModule

```
var upload = angular.module('UploadModule', [ 'ngResource','flow','UnikaPage' ]).config(
        [ 'flowFactoryProvider', 'AuthService', function(flowFactoryProvider,AuthService) {
            AuthService.getKeycloak();
            flowFactoryProvider.defaults = {
                target : '/ng-flow-java/upload',
                permanentErrors : [ 500, 501 ],
                maxChunkRetries : 1,
                chunkRetryInterval : 5000,
                simultaneousUploads : 4,
                progressCallbacksInterval : 1,
                withCredentials : true,
                method : "octet"
            };
            flowFactoryProvider.on('catchAll', function(event) {
                console.log('catchAll', arguments);
            });
            // Can be used with different implementations of Flow.js
            // flowFactoryProvider.factory = fustyFlowFactory;
        } ]);
```

But I get AuthService is undefined,  I tried without loading UploadModule  in UnikaPage, I dont get errors but my UploadModule wont load.

Can I get a problem of circular dependencies on UnikaPage and UploadModule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call some things at config stage. For example, if you need to setup the `Upload Module` on config but, at the same time, you need to run the `AuthService`, you will not be able to do that, because this stage is to setup the services.

You can intercept the `UploadModule` `AJAX ($http)` calls with one `$http` interceptor, evaluate what you need to handle, and then let the request be made.

Here, on the Angular.js API Reference (supposing that you are using a version 1.2.x), you can see how to setup an interceptor, dealing with the requests on the fly: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors.

Also, another thing to keep in mind is that you need to provide a way to load and fill up the `AuthService` with its token and etc before the `UploadModule` dispatch something. If you need to identify some `requestError` that can occur, returning a `401 (Not Authorized)`, for example, you can setup an interceptor for that too, so you can call a login window, for example, to get the credentials of the user.

## Edit 1:

I saw the code of `ngFlow`... You are using the `flowInit` directive to run, don't you? So you can pass to the directive `flowInit` an object scoped in your controller, for example, and extend the defaults that you've defined on `config()` stage. Following the original `flow.js` options, you can define a `headers` property, where you can define the headers for that situation.

```
<div flow-init="flowOptions">
    ...
</div>
```

On the controller:

```
angular.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.flowOptions = {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'token-here'
        }
    };
}]);
```

## Edit 2 (Solution):

It ended up removing the `defaults` that were defined on config(), letting to controller define the entire `flowInit` options.

Looking over the source code of ngFlow its possible to see that they use the native `angular.extend()` which doesn't have recursive traversing inside the object. Read more here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that UploadModule is using ng-flow, and it doesnt use $http to upload the pieces of the site

Comment: Thanks, it was a good a idea, but it doesnt work, I guess flow-init gets overriden at some point.  I looked on the headers, I even tried adding flow-init="{headers :.....}" manually with a token but it doesnt work.  Maybe the provider overrides flow-init.

Comment: Try to remove the defaults that you defined on `config()`, and let the controller to define the `flowInit`. Looking over the source code of `ngFlow` its possible to see that they use the native `angular.extend()` which doesn't have recursive traversing inside the object. It can be a paliative, and they need to fix this on their port of `flow.js`, because the options can have another levels inside the main object. Read a little bit here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend

Comment: Another option is to setup an `Flow.js` native object defined on your controller, and pass it through `flowObject` attribute of the directive. In this way there's no possibility to fail on passing the params you need!

Comment: Thanks, it worked I removed the defaults part in the .config. You rock

Comment: I was just about the solution 2 to the post

Comment: Do you preffer to add the solution to you question?

Comment: Leave it, it is ok like that i think

Answer (score 1):

Remove the circular dependency. Move `AuthService` to its own module

```
angular.module('AuthModule', [])
    .factory('AuthService', function() {
        var kc = {};

        // etc
    });
```

Then add it to the `UploadModule` dependencies

```
angular.module('UploadModule', ['ngResource', 'flow', 'AuthModule'])
```

Comment: Yeap this makes more sense

Comment: Sorry this doesnt work, as I have being told you cant inject a service on config, $inject is created after config.