# ngFlow - send CSRF_token via angular to laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, ng-flow

i am uploading files with ngFlow to laravel.
the CSRF token is sent via ajax 
with:

`<script>angular.module("app").constant("CSRF_TOKEN", '[[ csrf_token() ]]');</script`>

and its injected to the controllers via a service.

how would i atach the token to the request?

Comment: See this question instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31016585/injecting-a-service-into-a-provider/31040808?noredirect=1#comment50144461_31040808

Comment: It points out how to do it with ngFlow and Angular, due to a limitation of ngFlow

Answer (score 0):

Question is very old, you can try this way passing it through flow-init.

```
flow-init="{headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'}}"
```

Hope it helps someone !